# How to print the word but with the first letter as a capital

Tags: c++, c++17

Hello I am trying to do problem word capitalization  on code forces and to do the problem i am trying to use ascii table(my professor said I cant use cmath and anything other than loops arrays ascii table and the basics) it prints the number of the capital letter on the ascii lets say the ascii code for small a is 96 and capital A is 100 it prints 100 not A here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    char x=s[0];
    cout<<x+22<<s;
}
```

Comment: *small a is 96 and capital A is 100* - where have you got it? How have you got 100 from 96+22?

Comment: Unrelated: Always test the stream state after an IO transaction before you use the result of that transaction. It would really suck if `cin>>s;` failed to read a string and there is no `s[0];`.

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment question. This is probably not the correct forum for that.

Comment: `char x = std::toupper(s[0]);`, q.v. [std::toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper), since ASCII is a given.  Unicode (e.g., UTF-8) or other code pages might require additional effort.

Answer (score 1):

Because `22` is an `int`, the type of `x+22` is also `int`. You need to convert it back into a `char` for iostream to interpret it as a character:

```
cout << char(x+22) << s;
```

Note that I only addressed what you asked about: A number being printed instead of a character. There might be other small errors in there for you to find.

Comment: Even if both values are `char`, the type of the sum (`x + (char)22`, for example) is `int`. Integer types that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) in arithmetic expressions. +1.\